# Inserting Records into Array in JavaScript (intro to javascript student)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new at JavaScript, and am struggling with understanding how information gets from an external record set into an array. I'm hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong. I am just starting out and haven't learned much in the world of coding, so the following is very bare bones. Any help is appreciated!

This is what should occur:

- Open `recordset`
- Loop through `recordset`
- For each record in the `recordset`

  - Loop through `arrayZipCode[]`
  - If zip code is unique, add to `arrayZipCode[]`
- Output `arrayZipCode` in HTML

Here's my code (it all goes to weed after I get into the record set):

```
// Declare global variables
var arrayZipCode = [];  // Array
var zipCodeRecords;  // Access to database
var index;  // This is to capture the array slots and count loops
var displayResults;  // Reference to list set up from HTML
var zipCode;  // value of zip code
var valueFound;  // boolean

// Set loop values
index = 0;

// Set display to reference html page
var displayResultsAs;




// Open the record set
function initializeZipCodeRecords() {
    zipCodeRecords = openZipCodeStudyRecordSet();
}

// Loop through the record set
function readNextZipCodeRecord() {
    while (zipCodeRecords.readNextRecord()) {
        zipCode      = zipCodeRecords.getSampleZipCode();

        // For each record in the recordset:
            // Loop through arrayZipCode
            // If zip code is unique, add to arrayZipCode
            // Output arrayZipCode in HTML
        if (arrayZipCode[arrayZipCode.length] = 0) {
            arrayZipCode[index] = zipCode;
        } else {
            while (index < arrayZipCode.length) {


// The results in alert are ALL codes, not only unique codes. Why?
                if (zipCode !== arrayZipCode[index]) {
                    arrayZipCode[index] += zipCode;
                 // alert(arrayZipCode + "-" + arrayZipCode.length); // Interesting results (75213,91343,10024-3)
                }
              index ++;
            }

        }

    }
}

function displayUniqueZipCodeList() {
    // Not working; moved to main module

}

/*
    Main Function Module
*/
function project5Part1() {
    initializeZipCodeRecords();
    readNextZipCodeRecord();

    displayResults = document.getElementById("displayResultsId");
    displayResults.innerHTML += "<li>";
            + arrayZipCode[index]
            + "</li>";
```

Comment: @Felix I think so "(intro to javascript student)"

Answer (score 0):

use the javascript `indexOf` method and `push` method

```
if (array.indexOf(value) == -1)
    array.push(value);
```

---

[**indexOf**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

> Returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

[**push**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

> Mutates an array by appending the given elements and returning the new length of the array.

Comment: Yep. This is a homework question. I have yet to get an understanding of how the array gets populated. Understandably, all examples I've found show literals in the array. @hunter, I assume the (value) is where I'd place my "zipCode" variable. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

In fact in Javascript things are simpler when compared to other languages. In plain Javascript ( no frameworks ), records are usually handled as array of objects. Below I have given simple demonstration of what you need. 
You can see it working here : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/mxwUZ/4/

```
// Declare global variables

// Array of records retrieved from Database
var zipCodeRecords;  

// Object for storing zip codes. Using Object avoids looping and searching
var zipCodesObject = {};  


function openZipCodeStudyRecordSet(){

    // Array of records retrieved from database.
    // Below this function returns sample array of records

    return [

        {name:"name1", age:"32", zip_code:"345678"},
        {name:"name2", age:"42", zip_code:"232323"},
        {name:"name3", age:"27", zip_code:"323232"},
        {name:"name4", age:"19", zip_code:"543534"},
        {name:"name5", age:"31", zip_code:"323232"},
        {name:"name6", age:"56", zip_code:"344234"},
        {name:"name7", age:"43", zip_code:"5646456"},
        {name:"name8", age:"67", zip_code:"6756765"},
        {name:"name9", age:"48", zip_code:"6565"},
        {name:"name10", age:"49", zip_code:"345678"},

    ];
}


// Open the record set
function initializeZipCodeRecords() {
    zipCodeRecords = openZipCodeStudyRecordSet();
}

// Loop through the record set
function readRecords() {

    for(var i = 0; i < zipCodeRecords.length; i++){

        var zipCode      = zipCodeRecords[i]["zip_code"];

        // Set the zip code as property of zipCodesObject. This avoids duplicates.
        zipCodesObject[zipCode] = true;

    }


 }


/*
   Main Function Module
 */
 function project5Part1() {

    initializeZipCodeRecords();
    readRecords();

    var displayResults = document.getElementById("displayResultsId");

    // Loop through zipCodesObject and add list element
    for(var zipcode in zipCodesObject){
       displayResults.innerHTML += ( "<li>" + zipcode + "</li>");
    }

}


project5Part1();
```